# Dynamic path without including whole directory

Tags: javascript, webpack

Im using Webpack DefinePlugin for bundle options, e.g:

```js
{
  FIRST: 'hello',
  SECOND: 'foo',
  THIRD: 'bar'
}
```

And include code based on these settings like this:

```js
if (FIRST) {
  // some logic
  require('path/' + FIRST + '.js');
  // some logic
}
if (SECOND) {
  // some logic
  require('path/' + SECOND + '.js');
  // some logic
}
if (THIRD) {
  // some logic
  require('path/' + THIRD + '.js');
  // some logic
}
// there are actually more...
```

That way if only `FIRST` is truthy, all the other `if` blocks don't end up in final bundle. All the instances of `some logic` are identical for each `if` block and there's a lot of it, including more requires.

I cannot write like this:

```js
function addModule (name) {
  // some logic
  require('path/' + name + '.js');
  // some logic
}

if (FIRST) addModule(FIRST);
// etc
```

Because then whole `path/` directory gets included into bundle, I don't want that.

Is there an elegant way to refactor my repetitive code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using dynamic import and specifically their [magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)?

You could specify this for example:

```
function addModule (name) {
   import(
    /* webpackInclude: /hello|foo|bar\.js/ */
    /* webpackPreload: true */
    `path/${name}`
  );
}
```

This way only `hello.js` `foo.js` `bar.js` will be bundled but **ONLY ONE** will be downloaded at runtime.

and `webpackPreload` will just take care in terms of performance to download this chunk in parallel to the current one. Just added it as I think it may be important

Comment: Does it work the same way in eager mode? I want all of them into same bundle and I was using requires because imports result in promises which makes code harder to follow.

Comment: you can use `/* webpackIgnore: true */ ` magic comment to disable code-spiting and promise generation